# Backup of filetype to remote system

Tags: rsync

All i want to do, is to recursively copy all files of one type, let's say *.txt files, into one directory at a remote system, that i can reach with password less ssh.
I tried rsync in particular but did not have any success. Could someone give me a hint?
Spent already couple hours here as well as in google, but no luck.

Edit:
`rsync -avPr --dry-run ~/*.txt user@remote:~/RSYNC_DIR/`
but this found only txt-files in root of my home directory

`rsync -avPr --dry-run ~/**.txt user@remote:~/RSYNC_DIR/`
didn't change anything.

Also trying
`rsync -avPr --dry-run ~/* --exclude=* --include=*.txt user@remote:~/RSYNC_DIR/`
didn't do what i want it to.

My goal is, to copy every file in my home directory, unregardless if it is in first level or very deep in directory structure over to remote site into one directoty, i.e. remote:~/RSYNCd_TXT_FILES/.

PS:
Yes, i know, that --dry-run is just testing and actual not transferring any data.
But, in the summary it showed, that it found only *.txt files in actual directory.

Main goal is to consolidate similar files from several systems at one point, so i can easily work with them from all system. Not at the same time, but like sync files remote to local, work local with them, sync back local to remote, open other system, do the same.
If the remote file on server is newer, newer should be kept.
If file with same exists in different directories, i'm fine with getting informed and sort it out manually.
It's more that i'm looking for smth like
`alias sync_files="rsync <files to be sync'd>"`
which i can easily use then.
Btw., `find ~ -name *.txt -print0 | rsync --files-from0 <dest>` did not work for me, as the local path does not exist remotely.

Comment: `rsync` will do the job, but what do you mean by "not have any success".  What problems are you having?  You should post what you've tried if you would like detailed assistance...  Something else you might want to consider is [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org/), which is also available as an Ubuntu package.

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are files with the same name in different original directories?